dlib installation error in pycharm - returned non-zero exit status 1
l\\Temp\\pip-install-seak6ipf\\dlib_ff32f91edd9f4cafb1bd174c8cc6df1f\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
PS C:\Users\jatin bagul\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>

I have tried to install dlib, but this error is shown

that is not an error that shows any meaningful information.  Also, you probably dont have visual studio installed. It and cmake is required for compilation as dlib does not provide prebuilt wheels.
